# AJAX/PHP/MySQL - Detect database changes and alert user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Jquery:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "order",
        timeout: 30000,
        cache: true,
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    $('#changes').append(data);
alert("x amount of changes have been updated");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
        }
      });
```

**PHP:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `date` > NOW()");
//Other MySQL stuff
```

Basically I have no idea how I would do this, but I want to alert a user everytime there is a new order, but how exactly would I go about on the PHP side of alerting the user that there has been a change?

My brain is just not working today, I need to detect how many orders there have been and then append just the new orders to a table (And not the old ones)

Can I parse json from my order.php page but not display it and only display the HTML?

I really hope someone can help me out!

Comment: if you want to notify the user everytime the database changes, you'll need to google : `web sockets`, and unfortunately, it's not `php`'s strongest asset, it could be much easier with `NodeJs`

Comment: It can be done with PHP somehow, I just can't think how

Comment: I dont see any polling, you only calling it once. @Taki php is capable of doing running a websocket server just fine, node just has a simple api. but its not the only option, could do server-sent-events

Comment: What code would I write on the order.php side to store what changes there were, maybe in a JSON format to be read

Comment: well, you could run a cron job on any file that has been updated since its creation and logged as per the query done, or any days following, seems to be a way. It might be overkill, but it is a possible way.

Comment: or use `affected_rows()` and handle on that with conditionals.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i never said it can't :P , i was thinking about a simple example to provide, what do you think about a request every x secondes ?

Comment: A request every x seconds would just be reloading the data, I only want to append new records

Comment: I would just pass a count back and forth.  Count in PHP, store in Javascript.  Next call PHP say there are 10 records JS say there are 9, you know 1 was added.  Use `setInterval(function(){ //Ajax goes here}, 5000)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send and receive JSON from PHP. The following is from a production system, but I have removed a lot of code from it just to show you the important stuff. You will need to add error checking logic, etc (the code may have syntax errors (typos), but is, as I said, functional):

```
<script>
function checkForNew() {
var POSTData='CMD=getNewInvoices&'; /* Your PHP script can handle different requests */
POSTData=POSTData + 'myData=' + pseudoSave;
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: './checkForNewInvoices.php',
    data: POSTData,
    async: false,
    error: function(data) {
      retData=data;
      // Do error stuff
    },
    success: function(data) {
      retData=data;
      retJ=JSON.parse(retData);
      // Check here if valid JSON
    }
});
setTimeout(function() { checkForNew(); }, 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkForNew();
});

</script>

<?php {checkForNewInvoices.php}
  ... 
  ...
  echo json_encode($myJsonData); /* If data is in an array */
?>
```

Here is what I would do (logic/thinking {warning may be flawed :-)} ):

1. When I save the order (update/insert) I would update a text file (or db field) with an integer or 'flag (true/false)'.
2. My web-site, when loaded, will start with the count and the status of the flag, check for orders that don't have the processed flag and keep a local 'tag' of the loaded status.
3. I will then check if the flag/int has changed (order without the status flag). If it has changed or has orders without the 'shown/processed' status then I know there are new orders/invoices and I will then send a server query (ajax) to retrieve the orders or count, etc.

Worries/conditions:

1. If the orders come from all over and the web sites are accessed by lots of people (many to many).
2. The orders come from lots of people but only one person is loading the monitor site (many to one).
3. Order site is one place and monitor site is one (one to one - easy).

Trust this helps.

Happy Easter!